# How should i process the data in a json/dataframe format so that is suitable for rasa chatbots

Tags: nlp, rasa-nlu, rasa

I'm new with NLP and the rasa api. I'm trying to prepare the data so that it can be used as training data for intent recognition. The function that I'm trying to use is:

```
from rasa_nlu.training_data import load_data   #Import function
train_data_rasa=load_data('/content/data_file.json') #Json file
```

However the next error pop ups:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

The json file is the result of using pandas.to_json() function. The original dataset, is the ATIS flight intent dataframe in which there are two columns: The text and the intent.
Here is a preview of the json file:

```
{"Intent":{"0":"atis_flight","1":"atis_flight_time","2":"atis_airfare","3":"atis_airfare","4":"atis_flight","5":"atis_aircraft","6" ........
```

I don't really know what is going on as the dataset seems to be clean. I have also tried multiple alternatives such as markdown (md) type of file but it does not seem to work.

Thank you in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to try the [rasa data convert](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/command-line-interface/#rasa-data-convert-nlu) command (that converts your training data from json to yml format) and then try to train your data (with command `rasa train` from the `cli`) to see if you get the same error. Also, the [Training Data format](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/training-data-format) page in the docs might be a useful resource for you since it explains the types of training data and their expected structure. Another idea would be to post your question also on the Rasa forum where there might be more people that have encountered the same error like [here](https://forum.rasa.com/t/train-core-return-error-attributeerror-str-object-has-no-attribute-get/20503/4). That way you might get more ideas on how to solve your issue or more people will jump in and help.